# Unable to install an application via Android Studio

Tags: android, installation, huawei-mobile-services

I'm currently coding an android application, and since yesterday, my phone refuses to install it. I've checked the logs available via ADB, and I found a line saying: `PackageManager: Package com.package.example signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!`. So I decided to manually uninstall the previous version, but the error still remains, and the installation fails again and again. Does anyone know how to clean previous installations? I've tried to wipe cache from EMUI mode too.

**My phone: Huawei Mate 20 pro**

**EMUI version: 9.1.0**

Comment: you can use adb uninstall 'packagename' -- will remove for all users

Answer (score 2):

Remove the application for all the users.
You need to uninstall it because you are using a different signature than the original. If it is not working it might be because it is still installed for another user on the device. To completely uninstall, go to Settings -> Apps -> Options (the three dots on top right) -> Uninstall for all users